# exception:Not enough training instances (required: 1, provided: 0)! in weka

Tags: java, exception, weka, data-mining, k-means

i l have a dataset of movie in file moviedata.arff

```
@relation movie
@attribute annee numeric
@attribute Action numeric
@attribute Adventure numeric
@attribute Drama numeric
@attribute Romance numeric
@attribute Comedy numeric
@attribute Documentary numeric
@attribute Sci-Fi numeric
@attribute Triller numeric
@attribute Crime numeric
@attribute Musical numeric
@attribute Children numeric
@attribute Animation numeric
@attribute Horror numeric
@attribute Fantasy numeric
@attribute War numeric
@attribute Film-noir numeric
@attribute Western numeric
@attribute Mystery numeric
@data
%Toy Story%1995,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
%Jumanji%1995,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
%Grumpier Old Men%1995,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
%Waiting to Exhale%1995,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
%Father of the Bride Part II%1995,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
%Heat%1995,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
%Sabrina%1995,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
%Tom and Huck%1995,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
%Sudden Death%1995,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
%GoldenEye%1995,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
%The American President%1995,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

and i want to apply a this file a SimpleKmeans algorithm using java ans weka

```
public class generating_clusters {  
    BufferedReader breader;
    Instances Train;

    public generating_clusters() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "D:/workspace_java/JenaTutorial/moviedata.arff"));
        Train = new Instances(breader);
        SimpleKMeans kMeans = new SimpleKMeans();
        kMeans.setSeed(10);
        kMeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
        kMeans.setNumClusters(3);
        kMeans.buildClusterer(Train);
        int[] assignments = kMeans.getAssignments();
        int i = 0;
        for (int clusterNum : assignments) {
            System.out.printf("Instance %d -> Cluster %d", i, clusterNum);
            i++;
        } 
    }
}
```

but i have this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" weka.core.WekaException: weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans: Not enough training instances (required: 1, provided: 0)!
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1400)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1208)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1506)
    at weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans.buildClusterer(SimpleKMeans.java:595)
    at generating_clusters.<init>(generating_clusters.java:20)
    at generating_clusters.main(generating_clusters.java:32)
```

i don't undestand this exception, can you help me please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A) maybe **accept correct answers**? You have asked 17 questions, but never marked an answer as helpful. Unless you start giving credit by accepting helpful answers, people will stop bothering to answer at all.
B) study the error message more closely; and don't do **trial-error**-askAtSO cycles. For example here, the error message of Weka *was* helpful. It said you had 0 data in your file, and that is what you had. Please try harder to figure out such things yourself. Technically, none of these was a *programming* problem so far...

Comment: (To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Attribute-Relation File Format (ARFF):

> Lines that begin with a % are comments.

(http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html)

So given your moviedata.arff `@data` section, that could explain why there are no training instances being read in.

In other words, when the exception says "Not enough training instances (required: 1, provided: 0)", it means it quite literally. It thinks you have not provided any instances because they are all commented out in your arff file.